# Adding a Reference Column to an Existing Table During Association in Rails3.2.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models in my rails application. One is User that I have generated through with Devise and another one is Links. Now Initially There was only the Link model in my application. So I had two columns in my model Link namely **"id"** and **"link"** . Now my requirements have changed and I need implement a User model. A user in my application has one or many links. So added the line `has_many :links` to my **"user.rb"** and `belongs_to :users` to my **"link.rb"** file.

And I generated a migration like:

```
rails generate migration add_user_id_to_link user:references
```

That is, I'm generating a migration file to modify my existing table **"links"** and add a reference column **"user_id"** to the table.

But it's giving an error when running `rake db:migrate`. Then I ran the command:

```
rails genearate migration add_user_id_to_links user_id:integer
```

But it's giving a command not found error. Now the question is how do I achieve this??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the references helper only works for `create_table`. Which is why the first command doesn't work.

The second command should have worked though. The error is perhaps pointing to your typo in `generate`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Oh, by the way I'd be remiss if I didn't mention that you should really add an index too when creating a new reference. `references` would do that for you, but adding an integer in a migration doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `rails g migration add_user_id_to_links user_id:integer:index` if you want to assign each user to a link that they have posted.